# Highcharts variable pie legendItemClick does not hide or update data

Tags: javascript, events, highcharts, pie-chart

I am currently working with HighCharts variable Pie chart. I wanted to add more functionality to the legend click, so I added a separate legendItemClick event to perform two things: it should behave like the default (which it doesn't), but also correct the text value inside the donut, which also does not work.

Here is some code to work with:

```
            this._chart = Highcharts.chart(this.$.chartsContainer, {
                title: {
                    text: '<div style="font-size: 30px; font-weight:600;">' + ySum + '</div><div>Total demands</div>',
                    align: 'center',
                    verticalAlign: 'middle',
                    useHTML: true,
                    style: {
                        'font-size': '16px',
                        'font-weight': 'normal',
                        'text-align': 'center',
                        'text-transform': 'inherit'
                    },
                    x: -2,
                    y: -27,
                },
                colors: ['#315674', '#006281', '#006D81', '#00BFE2', '#53A1B4', '#4FB4B5', '#00E8D2', '#FFC35F', '#9ECBD6'],
                plotOptions: {
                    series: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: false },
                        showInLegend: true,
                        style: {'border-radius': '15px', 'font-weight': 'normal'},

                    },
                    variablepie: {
                        name: '',
                        borderWidth: 5, borderColor: 'white', minPointSize: 16,
                        color: 'white', innerSize: '60%',
                        point: {
                            events: {
                                legendItemClick: function(event) {
                                    console.log(event);
                                    if (this.visible) {
                                       this.series.visible = false;
                                        ySum = ySum - event.target.options.y;
                                    } else {
                                        ySum = ySum + event.target.options.y;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                },
                tooltip: {
                    useHTML: true,
                    headerFormat: '<small>{point.y}</small><table>',
                    pointFormat: '',
                    footerFormat: ''
                },
                series: [{
                    type: 'variablepie',
                    data: ySerie,
                },
                ]
            });
            this.reflowChart();
```

I tried hiding the clicked series data via its visible attribute, but that does not work properly, because it hides the clicked data, but does not redraw the chart to form a full circle again ( if you know what I am talking about ).

The second problem is the text title. I want it to show the new corrected value ( it is the ySum variable up inside the title: { text: block ). I tried setting the new value but it does not update the chart's data for some reason. For example, we have 3 slices of value 10 each. It shows "30 total". When 1 legend item is clicked and hidden, it should update ySum to now show " 20 total".

So in short, I need help with
1) How to properly hide and show clicked legend series data
2) Make the text attribute ySum update its value accordingly

Thank you for your help!

------------------- UPDATE -----------------

I figured out the first problem by myself ( I will leave the problem nonetheless if anyone else faces it ):
legendItemClick event is a function that can return a boolean value:
You can manipulate its behavior by setting
true = standard behavior -> it will hide the data series AND redraw the chart
false = it will do nothing -> similar as event.preventDefault()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change chart title you can use `setTitle` method:

```
    legendItemClick: function(event) {
      var chart = this.series.chart

      if (this.visible) {
        // this.series.visible = false;
        ySum = ySum - event.target.options.y;
      } else {
        ySum = ySum + event.target.options.y;
      }
      chart.setTitle({
        text: ySum
      }, false, false);

      return true
    }
```

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#setTitle

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sdh1y0tw/

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot ppotaczek! :-)